# Slow SAMBA Share on Debian 10 Compared to Old Server 2003 SMBv1 Share

Tags: visual-foxpro, samba

We are trying to use a Debian 10 VM to replace a 2003 server VM with an SMBv1 share. We have witnessed extremely slow Visual FoxPro performance when connecting to the new active directory SAMBA share (on the Debian 10 system) compared to the old (2003 SMBv1) share. We are using a Windows AD environment and have connected SAMBA to it using this guide: [Connecting SAMBA to AD](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/SAMBA_Share_with_Active_Directory_Login_on_Ubuntu_12.04.html). Our Debian 10 install uses almost all default settings, except for the fact that the swap files has been changed from 60 to 10. Is there any configuration changes we could make in the Debian setup file to speed things up? Below is the entire smb.conf file contents.

```
#
# Sample configuration file for the Samba suite for Debian GNU/Linux.
#
#
# This is the main Samba configuration file. You should read the
# smb.conf(5) manual page in order to understand the options listed
# here. Samba has a huge number of configurable options most of which 
# are not shown in this example
#
# Some options that are often worth tuning have been included as
# commented-out examples in this file.
#  - When such options are commented with ";", the proposed setting
#    differs from the default Samba behaviour
#  - When commented with "#", the proposed setting is the default
#    behaviour of Samba but the option is considered important
#    enough to be mentioned here
#
# NOTE: Whenever you modify this file you should run the command
# "testparm" to check that you have not made any basic syntactic 
# errors. 

#======================= Global Settings =======================

[global]

## Browsing/Identification ###

# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
# Mapped to AD - <Domain> / <DomainURL>
   workgroup = <Domain>
   security = ADS
   realm = <DomainURL>.COM

   vfs objects = acl_xattr
   map acl inherit = Yes
   store dos attributes = Yes

   dedicated keytab file = /etc/krb5.keytab
   kerberos method = secrets and keytab

   winbind use default domain = yes
   winbind nested groups = yes
   winbind refresh tickets = yes
   winbind offline logon = true

   # Just a member server
    domain master = no
    local master = no
    preferred master = no

#  Remove 2 lines below before going live
   winbind enum users = yes
   winbind enum groups = yes

#  Map <Domain>\Administrator to root account
   username map = /etc/samba/user.map
   
#  Samba Perforamnce Tweaks
   strict allocate = Yes
   server signing = No
   strict locking = No
   socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_RCVBUF=131072 SO_SNDBUF=131072
   min receivefile size = 16384
   use sendfile = Yes
   aio read size = 16384
   aio write size = 16384
   read raw = yes 
   write raw = yes 

#  Additional Samba Settings
   oplocks = yes               
   max xmit = 65535
   dead time = 15
   getwd cache = yes
   lpq cache = 30

#### Networking ####

# The specific set of interfaces / networks to bind to
# This can be either the interface name or an IP address/netmask;
# interface names are normally preferred
#;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0

#  Mapped to VMXNET3 adapter only
interfaces = ens192

# Only bind to the named interfaces and/or networks; you must use the
# 'interfaces' option above to use this.
# It is recommended that you enable this feature if your Samba machine is
# not protected by a firewall or is a firewall itself.  However, this
# option cannot handle dynamic or non-broadcast interfaces correctly.
#;   bind interfaces only = yes

#  Force to SMB port only and to specific interface
bind interfaces only = yes
smb ports = 445

#### Debugging/Accounting ####

# This tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
# that connects
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

# Cap the size of the individual log files (in KiB).
   max log size = 1000

#  Remove logging
   log level = 0

# We want Samba to only log to /var/log/samba/log.{smbd,nmbd}.
# Append syslog@1 if you want important messages to be sent to syslog too.
   logging = file

# Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d

####### Authentication #######

# Server role. Defines in which mode Samba will operate. Possible
# values are "standalone server", "member server", "classic primary
# domain controller", "classic backup domain controller", "active
# directory domain controller". 
#
# Most people will want "standalone server" or "member server".
# Running as "active directory domain controller" will require first
# running "samba-tool domain provision" to wipe databases and create a
# new domain.
   server role = standalone server

   obey pam restrictions = yes

# This boolean parameter controls whether Samba attempts to sync the Unix
# password with the SMB password when the encrypted SMB password in the
# passdb is changed.
   unix password sync = yes

# For Unix password sync to work on a Debian GNU/Linux system, the following
# parameters must be set (thanks to Ian Kahan <<kahan@informatik.tu-muenchen.de> for
# sending the correct chat script for the passwd program in Debian Sarge).
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

# This boolean controls whether PAM will be used for password changes
# when requested by an SMB client instead of the program listed in
# 'passwd program'. The default is 'no'.
   pam password change = yes

# This option controls how unsuccessful authentication attempts are mapped
# to anonymous connections
   map to guest = bad user

########## Domains ###########

#
# The following settings only takes effect if 'server role = primary
# classic domain controller', 'server role = backup domain controller'
# or 'domain logons' is set 
#

# It specifies the location of the user's
# profile directory from the client point of view) The following
# required a [profiles] share to be setup on the samba server (see
# below)
;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
# Another common choice is storing the profile in the user's home directory
# (this is Samba's default)
#   logon path = \\%N\%U\profile

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the location of a user's home directory (from the client
# point of view)
;   logon drive = H:
#   logon home = \\%N\%U

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the script to run during logon. The script must be stored
# in the [netlogon] share
# NOTE: Must be store in 'DOS' file format convention
;   logon script = logon.cmd

# This allows Unix users to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  The example command creates a user account with a disabled Unix
# password; please adapt to your needs
; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u

# This allows machine accounts to be created on the domain controller via the 
# SAMR RPC pipe.  
# The following assumes a "machines" group exists on the system
; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u

# This allows Unix groups to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  
; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g

############ Misc ############

# Using the following line enables you to customise your configuration
# on a per machine basis. The %m gets replaced with the netbios name
# of the machine that is connecting
;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m

# Some defaults for winbind (make sure you're not using the ranges
# for something else.)

#  Added <Domain> Domain
   idmap backend = tdb
   idmap uid = 10000-99999
   idmap gid = 10000-99999
   idmap config <Domain> : backend = rid
   idmap config <Domain> : range   = 100000-999999

# Template settings for login shell and home directory
   template shell = /bin/false
   template homedir = /home/%D/%U

#  Additional AD / Samba Authentication Settings
   client use spnego = no
   client ntlmv2 auth = no
   
   client lanman auth = yes
   
   encrypt passwords = yes
   restrict anonymous = 2

# Setup usershare options to enable non-root users to share folders
# with the net usershare command.

# Maximum number of usershare. 0 means that usershare is disabled.
#   usershare max shares = 100

# Allow users who've been granted usershare privileges to create
# public shares, not just authenticated ones
#   usershare allow guests = yes

#  Remove printing shares as its not necessary on ERPSERVER
   load printers = no
   printing = bsd
   printcap name = /dev/null
   disable spoolss = yes

#  Force to SMBv1 For VFP
   min protocol = NT1
   max protocol = SMB2

#======================= Share Definitions =======================

[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = no

# By default, the home directories are exported read-only. Change the
# next parameter to 'no' if you want to be able to write to them.
   read only = yes

# File creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create files with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
   create mask = 0700

# Directory creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create dirs. with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
   directory mask = 0700

# By default, \\server\username shares can be connected to by anyone
# with access to the samba server.
# The following parameter makes sure that only "username" can connect
# to \\server\username
# This might need tweaking when using external authentication schemes
   valid users = %S

# Un-comment the following and create the netlogon directory for Domain Logons
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
;[netlogon]
;   comment = Network Logon Service
;   path = /home/samba/netlogon
;   guest ok = yes
;   read only = yes

# Un-comment the following and create the profiles directory to store
# users profiles (see the "logon path" option above)
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
# The path below should be writable by all users so that their
# profile directory may be created the first time they log on
;[profiles]
;   comment = Users profiles
;   path = /home/samba/profiles
;   guest ok = no
;   browseable = no
;   create mask = 0600
;   directory mask = 0700

[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700

# Windows clients look for this share name as a source of downloadable
# printer drivers
[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no
# Uncomment to allow remote administration of Windows print drivers.
# You may need to replace 'lpadmin' with the name of the group your
# admin users are members of.
# Please note that you also need to set appropriate Unix permissions
# to the drivers directory for these users to have write rights in it
;   write list = root, @lpadmin

#AD Share for G Drive
[newgdrive]
   comment = GDrive
   path = /shares/newgdrive   
   valid users = "@<Domain>\Domain Users"
   force group = "domain users"
   writable = yes
   read only = no
   force create mode = 0660
   create mask = 0777
   directory mask = 0777
   force directory mode = 0770
   access based share enum = yes
   hide unreadable = yes   
   veto oplock files = /*.dbf/*.DBF/*.fpt/*.FPT/*.cdx/*.CDX/
```

Comment: First off you should obtain a network trace of the traffic between the important endpoints in this scenario with a specific focus on TCP traffic to determine *where* the slow down is coming from.  Without that, we would only be speculating.

Comment: @T-Heron I just did a network trace and it is consistently less than 1ms. Both the server hosting the share and the server with the access speed issue are on the same virtual network segment and connected to the same virtual switch, there are no hops to get there. It seems like the speed issue is specifically coming from the SAMBA share rather than the network connection. I'm looking for tools to test this out now.